# How to connect model and view model property using ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui, avalonia

I am using MVVM with ReactiveUI. I have a property in the model that I want to display and be able to edit in the UI. Is there any simple way to do this using ReativeUI? The following properties should be fulfilled:

- The model property implements INotifyPropertyChanged
- The model property can be changed from the view model or from the model
- Updates from within the model can be made on any thread
- Updates from the view model should use a throttle so that not every keystroke becomes a model update
- The application can be run with a UI or command line only, and the code should also be runnable in unit tests and integration tests
- When using an UI, the PropertyChanged event of the ViewModel needs to be raised on the UI thread
- The throttle can't be blocking in either run mode
- The code should be robust, i.e. not have the risk of causing deadlocks or reverting back to old values.

I somehow imagined this would be a standard case of how to wire a view model to a model but haven't managed to get this to work, and can't really figure out any way to make it work without quite a lot of code for a seemingly simple task.

Sample code of a non-working implementation:

```
public interface IModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly IModel model;

    public SomeViewModel(IModel model)
    {
        MyProperty = String.Empty;
        this.model = model;
        var inputThrottleTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        var scheduler = RxApp.MainThreadScheduler is AvaloniaScheduler
            ? RxApp.MainThreadScheduler
            : RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler;
        // This doesn't work. If updates are made in the model inputThrottleTime apart, the old value might be reassigned to the model.
        // And also, WhenAnyValue shouldn't be used to listen on properties that might be updated on background threads according to ReactiveUI devs.
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.model.MyProperty).ObserveOn(scheduler).Subscribe(p => MyProperty = p);
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.MyProperty).Skip(1).Throttle(inputThrottleTime, scheduler)
            .Subscribe(p => model.MyProperty = p);
    }
    
    [Reactive] public string MyProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some circular delay thing where the model property updates the view model property and then that goes through the throttle and back into the model property again. Typically you would not have the model updated while the user is inputting data IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding. Chose your control component in view(xaml). After that you give a datacontext for this view. There are different ways for giving data context and item source for controls. You can do this in xaml file like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

After that you can access variables. This variables must have get set properties and you can use ReactiveUI in here.

```
  public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
}
```

I used this in Avalonia. For more information you can look this: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding

Comment: The question was related to Model and ViewModel, not ViewModel and View.

Comment: When you equate one object with another, the values ​​will change because the objects will be the same. Because of that you don't need to use ReactiveUI.